# UnboundLocalError, and TypeError

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am a beginner. My error is `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment`. I have looked for answers but I dont understand most of the code.

```
def numberOfSquares(n):#This is where I get the user input.
    n= int(input("Please input a number higher than 1 to be the number of squares drawn."))
    while n < 0:
        print("Please try another number.")
        n= int(input("Please input a number higher than 1 to be the number of squares drawn."))
    print("Thanks for your contribution!")

def main():# I call the other function in this one, and draw n number of squares. I have not even put #the different colors on it yet.   
    numberOfSquares(n)
    import turtle
    for i in range(n):
        turtle.circle(40,steps= 4)
        turtle.left(45)
        turtle.forward(50)
        n-=1
    turtle.write("Colors of the Rain")

main()
```

Comment: You can't get two error messages by running the same code. Please ask about the particular problem you have with your code. Also, it's better to provide the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are misusing method variables. You are passing `n` to `numberOfSquares` while you really want to get a return value instead.

```
def number_of_squares():
    # Your code here, and finally
    return n
```

Then in your `main()`:

```
n = number_of_squares()
```

As to the second error, you have a typo. The method `turtle.cicrle` receives `steps` argument not `step`.

```
turtle.circle(40, steps=4)
```

And finally, there is a strong naming convention in python. All methods should be lower-case with underscores like `number_of_squares`, not camel-case (`numberOfSquares`).